# Implement subroutine for repeating code in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering is there any way to shorten my current code. I am running one process in a lot of my macros and was thinking about subroutine. I have tried several approaches but can't get it work.

I am performing one search several times:

```
Sub AddFileToDC()

    '... I am getting oDCSearchConditions from the search, then

    ' Execute the search
    Dim oDCObjectSearchResults As MFilesAPI.ObjectSearchResults
    Set oDCObjectSearchResults = oVault.ObjectSearchOperations.SearchForObjectsByConditions(oDCSearchConditions, MFSearchFlagNone, False)

    ' Get a reference to the existing document collection
    Set oDocumentCollectionOVAP = oVault.ObjectOperations.GetObjectVersionAndProperties(oDCObjectSearchResults.Item(1).ObjVer)

    Set oOldDocumentOVAP = oVault.ObjectOperations.GetObjectVersionAndProperties(oObjectSearchResults.Item(1).ObjVer)

End Sub
```

In all other macros I am performing another search from where I get `oObjectSearchResults`.

Instead of copying code above to all my macros, is it possible to do something like:

```
Sub Code1()

    '... I am getting oSearchConditions from the search, then

        ' Execute the search
        Dim oObjectSearchResults As MFilesAPI.ObjectSearchResults
        Set oObjectSearchResults = oVault.ObjectSearchOperations.SearchForObjectsByConditions(oSearchConditions, MFSearchFlagNone, False)

    AddFileToDC

End Sub
```

Now while running `Code1` I am getting error message saying variable `oDCObjectSearchResults` not defined as it is in another sub `AddFileToDC`...

Comment: You can't have the same variable name in both sets of code as the memory is already allocated for that specific variable name; your call for the macro `AddFileToDC` needs to have the dimensioning/setting removed for that variable being dimensioned/set in `Code1`.  You will most likely need to dimension the variable globally so both subroutines can utilize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making your like-named variable a global variable, while removing the setting/dimensioning from the called macro after you have set the variable:

```
Public oObjectSearchResults As MFilesAPI.ObjectSearchResults

Sub Code1()

        ' Execute the search
        Set oObjectSearchResults = oVault.ObjectSearchOperations.SearchForObjectsByConditions(oSearchConditions, MFSearchFlagNone, False)

    AddFileToDC

End Sub

Sub AddFileToDC()

    ' Get a reference to the existing document collection
    Set oDocumentCollectionOVAP = oVault.ObjectOperations.GetObjectVersionAndProperties(oDCObjectSearchResults.Item(1).ObjVer)

    Set oOldDocumentOVAP = oVault.ObjectOperations.GetObjectVersionAndProperties(oObjectSearchResults.Item(1).ObjVer)

End Sub
```